# Set date of transaction Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I want to set date of transaction Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce, but I dont know how.

I already defined my custom dimension, but in the date filter of the dashboard, Google show by upload transaction date, and not by my custom dimension.

It's possible to do that?

Comment: Can you show the code for how you're passing the data into the custom dimension, and also how you're associating that data with your ecommerce data?